# Can WAITFOR increase CXPACKET waits?

Tags: sql-server, parallelism, wait-types

If I have some T-SQL code like this:

```
While @done<1
Begin
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';
Set @done=<some select statement>
End
```

Is this likely to increase waits for `CXPACKET`? Presumably the other processor(s) will be waiting whilst `WAITFOR` is running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you issue a `WAITFOR` command, the task will start having a `wait_type` of `WAITFOR`.  This is a benign wait type and can be ignored.

Likewise, when this task enters the suspended state it will get off of the scheduler (processor) so it won't be taking up worker time.  We can see this with a simple example:

```
use AdventureWorks2012;
go

waitfor delay '00:10:00';
go
```

In another window you can run the following:

```
select
    session_id,
    command,
    status,
    wait_type
from sys.dm_exec_requests
where command = 'waitfor';
```

My results are as follows:

```
session_id  command   status      wait_type
54          WAITFOR   suspended   WAITFOR
```

As for your question of how this will reflect in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`, upon the `WAITFOR` wait type's completion, it will then increment the `WAITFOR` type in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` for the duration that the task was waiting for:

```
select *
from sys.dm_os_wait_stats
where wait_type = 'waitfor';
```

But as said previously, the `WAITFOR` wait type is benign and can generally be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

No. CXPACKET is caused by parallel processes running on the SQL Server instance.

More info [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/)

Comment: Yes, exactly. So if one process was running this piece of code would the other threads be waiting at the WAITFOR command?

Comment: The WAITFOR just delays the execution of the next line of code. There is nothing waiting on it. It holds no locks on anything.

Comment: Right, I understand. So whilst I'm waiting the 30 seconds, nothing will increase in sys.dm_os_wait_stats (for that command).

Comment: WAITFOR has no concern with CXPACKET, rather it will generate wait type of "WAITFOR". An animated video how waits occur http://www.connectsql.com/2014/04/video-sql-server-performance-tuning.html And What are CXPACKET waits http://www.connectsql.com/2014/04/video-sql-server-performance-tuning_27.html

Comment: That isn't quite correct.  It will increase the `WAITFOR` wait type in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`.